# jQuery button display in IE6

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, button, internet-explorer-6

We have some HTML buttons which we format using JQuery - `$('#button').button()`.

Works great but..  when the page first loads in IE6 you see the "unformatted" regular HTML button and then you see the JQuery formatting kick in a split second or so afterwards.

What can you do do avoid displaying the default HTML button and just display the JQuery formatted version?

Comment: Why are you still developing for IE6, weird how the rest of the world has moved on from IE6 other than, surprisingly, developers themselves...

Comment: @Andrew Dunn: this might due to business reasons, as Microsoft chose to extent the life of IE6 until 2014... that's even after 2012 :)

Comment: Maybe try looking to [this link](http://browsesad.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in a div which by default it hidden `CSS: #hiddenDiv {display: none;}` and then after you perform all of the styling on the button using jQuery unhide the div `$('#hiddenDiv').show()`

**Edit:**
To allow the button to be displayed when javascript is disabled:

```
<noscript>
    <style>
        #hiddenDiv
            {
            display: block!important;
            }
    </style>
</noscript>
```

**Important:** This will invalidate your HTML, as `style` tags are not allowed in `noscript` elements, and in XHTML noscript tags are not allowed in the `head` element.

Comment: this is not advisable. For if javascript is disabled, users wont see the button.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. In your CSS code, write

```
#button{
visibility: hidden
}
```

Put this code inside

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<![endif]-->
```

And in your $(document).ready function, add the following.

```
("#button").css("visibility","visible");
```

Screw them if they use IE6 and disable Javascript. :P

Comment: this is not advisable. For if javascript is disabled, users wont see the button.

Comment: simple solution, easy to implement. Yes it does mess up anyone in IE6 with JS turned off, but frankly that's just tough. To be honest, if the original problem just affects IE6 and fixes itself after page load, I'd just leave it as is. It works. Okay, so it doesn't look pretty, but you're using IE6; what do you expect??